# No more SQL Backups

Tags: google-cloud-sql

i used automated backups on Google Cloud. That worked perfect until one week ago.
Suddenly there are no more backups.
They are still activated, but there are no more backups.
There is no output in the logging section.

Is there a way to debug this?

thank you!

Comment: check if your account is expired

Comment: no its not. i am running (and paying) this service for 2 years now.

Comment: Just had the same problem: five days ago it sopped. Any news?

Answer (score 1):

We (CloudSQL service) had some problems with automated backups. It should be mitigated now, so your backups should resume now or very shortly. Manual backups still worked so it is a viable workaround as well.

Just to add: as with any other critical piece of data (managed or not), I'd highly recommend to set up a process of periodic end-to-end disaster restore testing.